# Create a PNG from SVG with JavaScript from command line

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to create a PNG image from an SVG that contains Javascript. The SVG file does not rely on external files. I need to do it from the command line or a Python script.

So far I have tried with `svgexport` and Inkscape without success.

Here is the test I used:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <text id='test' x='0' y='50'>NO</text>
 <script type='application/javascript'>document.getElementById('test').textContent='YES';</script>
</svg>
```

Both svgexport and Inkscape render it as "NO", so far only my browser (Firefox) renders it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

[`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is a webkit-based renderer, that can interpret Javascript. It passed my test case.

If you want to use it, be careful: the version from the Debian/Ubuntu repos is outdated and won't work outside of an X session (e.g. it won't work on a server).

Answer (score -1):

Use `rsvg-convert` utility, it clearly has the best conversion quality and exact correctness.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Librsvg